# someone can help me with FileNotFoundError python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

i'm trying to copy files from one folder to another, so i've start by creating the 2 folder and subfolder but the problem occured when i tried to copy file using shutil.copyfile(), the problem is when i run this code one slash(/) is added tho the end of my folder path.
find down my code.

```
original = 'Users\\Jonathan\\Documents\\datas'
base_direct = 'Users\\Jonathan\\Documents\\dataset'
os.mkdir(base_direct)
train_dir = os.path.join(base_direct, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
os.mkdir(train_cats_dir)
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
  src = os.path.join(original, fname)
  dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
  shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

so the error is saying:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users\\Jonathan\\Documents\\datas/cat.0.jpg'
```

the problem is on the slash between datas and cat

i'm using google colab.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend:

1. Use [absolute path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm), which should include a drive.
2. Use `pathlib` to create the parent folders to the final folder, and avoid errors. Instead of using `os.mkdir()`.
3. (Optional) Use [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-prefixes-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals), by adding an `r` before a path string to escape backslash. Does the same thing as a double back-slash but is neater.

**Full code**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

original = r'C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\datas' # assuming you are using C drive
base_direct = r'C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\dataset'

Path(base_direct).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

train_dir = os.path.join(base_direct, 'train')
Path(train_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'cats')
Path(train_cats_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]

for fname in fnames:
  src = os.path.join(original, fname)
  dst = os.path.join(train_cats_dir, fname)
  shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mention drive name some think like 'Z:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\datas'

Comment: i've tried it also, but i had the same error

Comment: Try with both  single and double  front and back slash.

in some cases the program location and file should be in same location

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).